# I can't find the limit of this sequence series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I can't solve this limit:
$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=?$ when:

$a_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k+1)*sin(\frac{k^2\pi}{n^2})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k+1)*\sin(\frac{k^2\pi}{n^2})$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2\frac{k}{n}+\frac{1}{n})*\sin(\frac{k^2\pi}{n^2})$$
$$=n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}(2\frac{k}{n}\sin(\frac{k^2\pi}{n^2})) + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\sin(\frac{k^2\pi}{n^2})$$

Now, as $n\to\infty$, we can convert the sums to an integral by taking $\frac{1}{n}=dx$ and $\frac{k}{n}=x$. We have:

$$a_n = n\int_{0}^{1}2x\sin(x^2\pi)dx + \int_o^1\sin(x^2\pi)dx$$
$$\approx \frac{2n}{\pi}+0.5 \approx \frac{2n}{\pi}$$
Thus, $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n}{\pi}=\infty$

Comment: The value of the limit is $\infty$.

Comment: @user yes, that is implied by the last line, anyways I’ve edited it

Comment: You should either remove $2n/\pi $ or precede it with "$\lim $".

Comment: @user I’ve added it!